# How to calculate running sums with append-only rows

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table where rows are never mutated but only inserted; they are immutable records. It has the following fields:

- `id`: `int`
- `user_id`: `int`
- `created`: `datetime`
- `is_cool`: `boolean`
- `likes_fruits`: `boolean`

An object is tied to a user, and the "current" object for a given user is the one that has the latest `created` date. E.g. if I want to update `is_cool` for a user, I'd append a record with a new `created` timestamp and `is_cool=true`.

I want to calculate how many users are `is_cool` at the end of each day. I.e. I'd like the output table to have the columns:

- `day`: some kind of `date_trunc('day', created)`
- `cool_users_count`: number of users that have `is_cool` at the end of this day.

What SQL query can i write that does this? FWIW I'm using Presto (or Redshift if need to).

Note that there are other columns, e.g. `likes_fruits`, which means a record where `is_cool` is `false` does not mean `is_cool` was just changed to `false` - it could have been `false` for a while.

This is what procedural pseudo-code would look like to represent what I'd want to do in SQL:

```
// rows = ...
min_date = min([row.created for row in rows])
max_date = max([row.created for row in rows])

counts_by_day = {}
for date in range(min_date, max_date):
  rows_up_until_date = [row for row in rows if row.created <= date]
  latest_row_by_user = rows_up_until_date.reduce(
    {},
    (acc, row) => acc[row.user_id] = row,
  )
  counts_by_day[date] = latest_row_by_user.filter(row => row.is_cool).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jus a query  ..  try using a sum on boolend and group by

```
  select  date(created), sum(is_cool)
  from  my_table  
  group by date(created)
```

or if you need the number of users

```
select t.date_created, count(*) num_user
from  (
  select  distinct date(created) date_created, user_id 
  from  my_table  
  where is_cool = TRUE 
 ) t 
 group by  t.date_created
```

or if need  the last value for  is_cool

```
select date(max_date), sum(is_cool)
from (
    select  t.user_id, t.max_date, m.is_cool, m.user_id 
    from my_table m  
    inner join  (
        select  max(date_created) max_date, user_id 
        from  my_table 
        group by  user_id, date(date_created)
    ) t on t.max_date  = m.date_created 
            and t.user_id  = m.user_id 
    where m.is_cool = TRUE 
) t2
group by date(max_date)
```

Comment: It's possible that `is_cool` changes back and forth for a user, which means there would multiple `is_cool=true` rows but that wouldn't represent multiple users who are `is_cool`.

Comment: your comment is not clear to me ..  try explain better or add  a data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Suppose I have the rows: `user:1, is_cool: true, created: 9am`, `user:1, is_cool: false, created: 10am`, `user:1, is_cool: true, created:11am`. The resulting output should be `1` because there is 1 user who `is_cool`, not `2` because there are 2 `is_cool` rows.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately that doesn't take into account that `likes_fruits` could be updated. E.g. user already `is_cool`, so a new row of `user:1, is_cool: true, likes_fruits: true` would not represent this user becoming `is_cool` this day. The count for each day should either be users who became cool today, or users who are cool as of this day.

Comment: I see that the 3rd query calculates the number of `is_cool` users as of now. I'd like that for every day from a historical perspective. I want the number of `is_cool` users as of day 1, as of day 2... etc.

Comment: ?? -... group by date(max_date)  return the number of is_cool user for each date

Comment: It doesn't consider the case where user1 was `is_cool` on day 1, was not `is_cool` on day 2, and became `is_cool` again on day 3. The result for day 1 should be `1`, day 2 should be `0`, and day 3 should be `1`. The 3rd query here would return `0` for day 1.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery might be the simplest solution.  The following gets the value of `is_cool` for each user on each date:

```
select u.user_id, d.date,
       (select t.is_cool
        from t
        where t.user_id = u.user_id and
              t.created < dateadd(day, 1, d.date)
        order by t.created desc
        limit 1
       ) as is_cool
from (select distinct date(created) as date
      from t
     ) d cross join
     (select distinct user_id
      from t
     ) u ;
```

Then aggregate:

```
select date, sum(is_cool)
from (select u.user_id, d.date,
             (select t.is_cool
              from t
              where t.user_id = u.user_id and
                    t.created < dateadd(day, 1, d.date)
              order by t.created desc
              limit 1
             ) as is_cool
      from (select distinct date(created) as date
            from t
           ) d cross join
           (select distinct user_id
            from t
           ) u
     ) ud
group by date;
```